# Can a ThreadPool be used from a Thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on a small app that will use threads to make some web requests. I want that when pressing X button a main [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) starts and that would manage the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), because depending on the results of the first group of threads I will have to open more or less threads after.

Is this a good practice or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "managing the thread pool" ?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you try expanding on the problem you are trying to solve. Posting some sample code or pseudo code could help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThreadPool can certainly be used from any thread in C#.

Let's say that when you click the button in your UI, it would call:

```
object state = ...some value...;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyHandler, state);

...

private void MyHandler(object state)
{
    object newState = ... do something with state ...
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleMoreWorkToDo, newState);
}
```

You just have to be careful about what resources you use in your handlers so they don't modify the state of an object that's being manipulated on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to fire off a thread and then allow it to use the thread pool to create additional threads. If that is the correct assumption, you can easily do this.

If you are talking about managing threads yourself, that is an option. Trying to truly manage the thread pool from your own code, that is nasty and as ill advised as trying to control the GC.

More or less threads is what the thread pool should help you with.